# Scrollview with Recyclerview inside loops scroll to the bottom (nonstop)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I'm having a weird issue here, the normal issue that the `ScrollView` only scrolls once, but in my case, it keeps scrolling and scrolling to the bottom.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:layout_gravity="end"/>

</FrameLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
                android:id="@+id/slider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/slider_height"
                />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/home_rv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/slider_rv_margin"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code:

```
    mScrollView = (ScrollView) mView.findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
    mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(mGridLayout) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {
            Log.i("Scroller","Scrolling: Page " + page + " - Total: " + totalItemsCount);
            mCurrentPage = mCurrentPage + 1;
            GetArticles(false);
        }
    });
```

The log keeps getting called, for example:

```
     10-06 15:55:33.027 794-794/com.testapp I/Scroller: Scrolling: Page 4 - Total: 16
     10-06 15:55:33.639 794-794/com.testapp I/Scroller: Scrolling: Page 5 - Total: 20
     10-06 15:55:34.264 794-794/com.testapp I/Scroller: Scrolling: Page 6 - Total: 24
     10-06 15:55:34.895 794-794/com.testapp I/Scroller: Scrolling: Page 7 - Total: 28
     10-06 15:55:35.573 794-794/com.testapp I/Scroller: Scrolling: Page 8 - Total: 32
     10-06 15:55:36.311 794-794/com.testapp I/Scroller: Scrolling: Page 9 - Total: 36
     10-06 15:55:36.923 794-794/com.testapp I/Scroller: Scrolling: Page 10 - Total: 40
     10-06 15:55:37.513 794-794/com.testapp I/Scroller: Scrolling: Page 11 - Total: 44
```

Answer (score 1):

What is that EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener?
It should be OnScrollListener right?
It may be causing the problem.

Comment: It's taken from here: https://gist.github.com/nesquena/d09dc68ff07e845cc622

Answer (score 0):

Use `<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>` instead of `<ScrollView>`

Comment: Using it won't solve my problem, when i'm using `NestedScrollView`, the scroll isn't working anymore.

Comment: Remove this line from the code and try     mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

Comment: Still, didn't solve the scroll issue, it won't scroll, no matter what i do.